# how to destroy static data member in OOP?

Tags: c++, oop

if i am using a **static data member** in a class like below in my code and declare more than **one object** of that class then which object will **destroy** the static data member **martians**?

```
class martianGame
{
    static int martians;
  public:
    martianGame();
    static int getMartian();
};
martianGame::martians = 50;
int main()
{
   martianGame game[10];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _"destroy"_ actually? Resetting the static data member to `0`?

Comment: None of them. The static object will be destroyed when the program terminates.

Comment: No i mean like objects are destroyed than by which the scope of static data member will end?

Comment: scope of the program

Comment: but why we declare "static variable" within the class?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We didn't write this.

Comment: If it's not `public`, then it's for encapsulation, which is a good thing. If it's `public`, then it's for style.

Comment: Declaring a variable generally neither starts nor ends anyone's lifeitme. It's only when you *define* a variable that lifetime starts to matter.

Answer (score 3):

> how to destroy static data member in OOP?

Static data members, just like all other objects that have static storage duration, are destroyed at the end of the program. So, to destroy a static data member, you need to return from `main` or call `std::exit`.

> which object will destroy the static data member martians?

None of the objects. The static member will be constructed and destroyed even if there are no instances of the class.